# Google drive showing custom UTI files dimmed in UIDocumentBrowserViewController controller

Tags: ios, uti, uidocumentbrowservc, flysystem-google-drive

We have created custom UTI of the file type in XML format for our iOS app. It is working fine for all other cloud service provider except for google drive. We are using UIDocumentBrowserViewController and defined our custom UTI in the app.plist file. Still, Google drive shows our application files as dimmed, as the user is unable to select the file stored in the drive. We can open the file if we provide public.xml as UTI in app.plist. But We don't want to open any XML format in our app, as we have customized XML tag for our app. Any help /point to get it solved would be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: We see the same in our app. It appears that Drive thinks the underlying file type is "XML". You can still get access by opening the UIDocumentPickerViewController with "public.xml" as one of the types, but then you may get other XML files that you didn't want.